# Hadoop MapReduce to get percentage of each word

Tags: hadoop, percentage, cpu-word

I am using Hadoop Mapreduce to get the word and word count information. Besides the count of each word, I also need to find the percentage of each word that show in the document. The output is like this.
If the document just contains three words "hello","world" and "kitty". The result should be like this.

word  count percentage

hello 40 0.4

world 50  0.5

kitty 10  0.1

I can set a `TOTAL_KEY` to count all words, the problem is that the result will return at the same time when each word count return. When output each word to hdfs, it is impossible to calculate the percentage at that time.

Comment: So why don't you write a second job to do that?

Comment: I think we have other choices..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
job.setJarByClass(WinnerCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(WinnerCountMapper.class);
    //job.setCombinerClass(WinnerCountCombiner.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(WinnerCountCombiner.class);
    job.setReducerClass(WinnerCountReducer.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(ChessInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputPath));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, temp);


    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    Counters counters = job.getCounters();
    Counter total = counters.findCounter(WinnerCountMapper.MAP_COUNTER.TOTAL_TUPLE);
    //System.out.println(total.getDisplayName()+":"+total.getValue());

    /*if (hdfs.exists(output))
        hdfs.delete(output, true);*/

    Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();
    conf2.set("total", total.getValue()+"");
    Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2,"aggregation");

    job2.setJarByClass(WinnerCount.class);
    job2.setMapperClass(AggregationMapper.class);
    job2.setReducerClass(AggregationReducer.class);
    job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a counter in your Mapper.

1. increment a global counter for counting total number of words while you emit the word from the mapper.
2. get the counter in your reducer to get the total number of words emitted.
3. calculate the percentage using the general method.

Comment: If I use a combiner, the counter will return for each combiner, not for the last reducer.

Comment: My solution doesn't include a combiner

Comment: Is it possible to use the combiner in the global counter logic? Combiner is mainly used to compress the data before reduce uses it.. I don't get it why the logic wouldn't work..

Comment: A combiner works only to reduce the data transfered from the map phase to the reduce phase. And it works locally for each map task. You can use the combiner to reduce  the mapper output. That is if u want "hello,1" to be emitted as "hello , 4" instead of just emitting it 4 times in that case, a combiner can be used. And it cannot be the same class as your reducer class since the combiner only counts the words and not find the percentage(which is your reducers logic).

Comment: Problem solved, thank you for your response, it should be gotten in the main class

Comment: Please rate for the answer